# React custom country select hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a reusable country select functionality by utilizing React Hooks. The idea behind the scenes is to create a function which would handle the country change within a custom select box. With this in mind, I have attempted the following code, which results in an endless loop. Is there any alternative to this code, or any ideas on how to implement it?

```js
const { useState } = require("react");

const useCountrySelect = (defaultCountires, defaultCountry) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  const filteredCountries = defaultCountires.filter(
    (country) => country !== defaultCountry
  );

  setCountries(filteredCountries);

  return [countries, setCountries];
};

export default useCountrySelect;
```

Hook usage in a component:

```js
const [country] = useCountrySelect(["lv", "ee", "lt"], "lt");
console.log(country);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, Why is your code resulting in an endless loop?
it is because when u call useCountrySelect hook it will call `setCountries(filteredCountries)`. now state is changed. react tries re-render the component. but in the rerendering process, `setCountries(filteredCountries)` will be called again. this will continue like a loop.

try this,

```
import {useState} from 'react'

const useCountrySelect = (defaultCountires, defaultCountry) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(() => {
    return defaultCountires.filter(
    (country) => country !== defaultCountry
  );
  });

  return [countries, setCountries];
};

export default useCountrySelect;
```

Comment: The state does not get updated on change (updated the question with the hook's usage) :(

Comment: @Aleksandrs I've tested the hook and it is working as expected. can you explain a bit of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`setCountries(filteredCountries);` is unconditionally enqueueing state updates and triggering the render looping. Just set the state initially.

```
const { useState } = require("react");

const useCountrySelect = (defaultCountires = [], defaultCountry) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(defaultCountires.filter(
    (country) => country !== defaultCountry
  ));

  return [countries, setCountries];
};

export default useCountrySelect;
```

[image: Edit react-custom-country-select-hook]

Usage:

```
const [country] = useCountrySelect(["lv", "ee", "lt"], "lt");
console.log(country);
```

Output:

> `["lv", "ee"]`

Comment: The state does not get updated on change (updated the question with the hook's usage) :(

Comment: @Aleksandrs Can you clarify what you mean? `["lv", "ee"]` is logged. The hook appears to function as I'd expect here in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-country-select-hook-hnw68g).

Comment: @Aleksandrs What state are you trying to update, and on *what* change are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why your state variable is an array. It seems you want the custom hook to return the selected country as well as a function to update it.

If my understanding is correct, here is a possible solution :

```js
const { useState } = require("react");

function useCountrySelect(countries, defaultCountry) {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(defaultCountry);

  // reset the country when input countries change
  useEffect(() => setCountry(defaultCountry), [countries.join()]);

  function setCountryWrapper(nextCountry) {
    // prevent updates with invalid country
    if (!countries.includes(nextCountry) {
      return;
    }

    setCountry(country);
  }

  return [country, setCountryWrapper, countries];
};

export default useCountrySelect;
```

Usage

```js
const [country, setCountry] = useCountrySelect(["lv", "ee", "lt"], "lt");
console.log(country);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const { useState, useEffect } = require("react");

function filter(defaultCountires, defaultCountry) {
  const filteredCountries = defaultCountires.filter(
    (country) => country !== defaultCountry
  );
  return filteredCountries;
}

const useCountrySelect = (defaultCountires, defaultCountry) => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(
    filter(defaultCountires, defaultCountry) // this will set the initial state
  );

  // side-effects like this should go inside `useEffect`
  useEffect(() => {
    setCountries(filter(defaultCountires, defaultCountry));
  }, [defaultCountires, defaultCountry]); // based on prop change, this effect will rerun again

  // don't set any state directly in the root component/hook body! Else you'll be stuck in an endless loop

  return [countries, setCountries];
};

export default useCountrySelect;
```

Comment: Looks like an endless loop is here when accessing the countries variable from another component?

Comment: that should not happen :/ Can you update the question to include this hooks usage

Comment: That's all sorted. sorry if I did understand something not right :(

Comment: [Here's the preview of my answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-darkness-q94mof) It is working as expected, unless you were hoping for something else

Comment: and what does the `setCountries` function do? I am new to this topic, but it seems unused. is it redundant?

Comment: I guess, you are missing major react concepts. As the other answers are similar to mine, `setCountries` sets or updates the `countries` variable. I'm guessing, you use this variable to list the dropdown/select menu.